# How to set width of line in 3D

Tags: directx-9, sharpdx

Am using SharpDX on DirectX 9 to draw a line.

Line is drawn correctly with the following code.

```
Vector3 startPoint= ...
Vector3 endPoint = ...
Vector3[] data = new Vector3[] { startPoint, endPoint };
device.DrawUserPrimitives<Vector3>(PrimitiveType.LineList, 1, data);
```

**Question 1**: How do we set the width of line?

**Question 2**: If a graphics card is used, then line width is less. 
if there is no graphics card, a thicker line has been drawn.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to Question 1**

Using Line class, we can set the width of line.

```
Matrix worldViewProjection = worldMatrix * viewMatrix * projectionMatrix;
Line line = new Line(device);
line.Width = 2;
ColorBGRA lineColor = new ColorBGRA(255, 0, 0, 255);
line.Begin();
line.DrawTransform(new Vector3[] { anchorPoint, cursorPoint }, worldViewProjection, lineColor);
line.End();
```

Question 2 is still unanswered.